# GAE files blocked due to mimetype/unknown url handler type for js files with multiple .'s

Tags: python-3.x, django, reactjs, google-app-engine

I've been hung up on deploying my React/Django app to GAE for the last two days and I think I've isolated the issue, but I've been unable to come up with a solution that works. When I first deployed I was running into issues with mimetypes with each of my JS and CSS files embedded in my index.html being blocked with error messages like these leading me to believe it found the files but didn't handle them correctly:

(file) was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

My understanding from browsing SO and doing research was that GAE was treating these as html files and not executing them properly. I started playing with the .yaml to enforce mime types due to some settings I saw in the references for GAE and now I can't deploy and get error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: [(mysite)\app.yaml]
Unknown url handler type.
<URLMap
    static_files=None
    upload=None
    application_readable=None
    static_dir=None
    mime_type=text/css
    expiration=None
    require_matching_file=None
    http_headers=None
    position=None
    api_endpoint=None
    redirect_http_response_code=None
    url=/static/css\.css
    login=optional
    auth_fail_action=redirect
    secure=default
    script=None
    >
  in "(mysite)/app.yaml", line 8, column 1
```

I've been playing around with the files in the browser and I've found that I get 404 errors when I try to pull up the files despite knowing that they're in the directory. IE navigating here: https://acptconstruction.appspot.com/backend/static/js/2.738f0ca9.chunk.js yields a 404, but I can see it with the exact filename in the directory. Because of that and the error message on deployment, I think that maybe GAE is having trouble parsing the filenames because of all of the periods? The filenames were built when I ran npm run-scripts build after I was finished with the front end app, but regardless, I tried to deploy copying that file to homepage.js and including using that exact filename with the path without success.

I don't know if I was on a better track with the first yaml file, where it could "find" them (I think) and not grock them or with the second yaml where they couldn't be found? The issue might be as simple as copying all the js files and changing their names to like homepage.js and homepage2.js but I am nervous that I might break everything if I go down that path. Any help is appreciated!

Files:

Originally, my app.yaml file looked like this:

```
runtime: python38

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

Updated YAML that gives the deployment errors:

```
runtime: python38
 
handlers:
- url: /static/css/(.*)
  mime_type: text/css
 
- url: /static/js/(.*)
  mime_type: text/javascript
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en" style="background-color:#f1f1f1"><head><base href="/"> <meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><meta name="ACPT Construction"/><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/><title>ACPT Construction</title><link type="text/css" href="/backend/static/css/2.89e89512.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"><link type="text/css" href="/backend/static/css/main.cfd2a7ed.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root" style="min-height:1000px"></div><script>!function(e){function t(t){for(var n,c,i=t[0],l=t[1],a=t[2],f=0,s=[];f<i.length;f++)c=i[f],Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,c)&&o[c]&&s.push(o[c][0]),o[c]=0;for(n in l)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(l,n)&&(e[n]=l[n]);for(p&&p(t);s.length;)s.shift()();return u.push.apply(u,a||[]),r()}function r(){for(var e,t=0;t<u.length;t++){for(var r=u[t],n=!0,i=1;i<r.length;i++){var l=r[i];0!==o[l]&&(n=!1)}n&&(u.splice(t--,1),e=c(c.s=r[0]))}return e}var n={},o={1:0},u=[];function c(t){if(n[t])return n[t].exports;var r=n[t]={i:t,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[t].call(r.exports,r,r.exports,c),r.l=!0,r.exports}c.m=e,c.c=n,c.d=function(e,t,r){c.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{enumerable:!0,get:r})},c.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},c.t=function(e,t){if(1&t&&(e=c(e)),8&t)return e;if(4&t&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var r=Object.create(null);if(c.r(r),Object.defineProperty(r,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&t&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var n in e)c.d(r,n,function(t){return e[t]}.bind(null,n));return r},c.n=function(e){var t=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return c.d(t,"a",t),t},c.o=function(e,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,t)},c.p="/";var i=this.webpackJsonpacptconstruction=this.webpackJsonpacptconstruction||[],l=i.push.bind(i);i.push=t,i=i.slice();for(var a=0;a<i.length;a++)t(i[a]);var p=l;r()}([])</script><script type="application/javascript" src="/backend/static/js/2.738f0ca9.chunk.js"></script><script type="application/javascript" src="/backend/static/js/main.b160e3e4.chunk.js"></script></body></html>
```

File structure:

```
acptconstruction
  backend
    settings.py
    manage.py (command to run server is python manage.py runserver)
    backend
        views.py (heres where index.html gets called)
    urls.py (url structure)
  acptconstruction (front end)
    build
        index.html
      manifest.json
  app.yaml
  static
    css
    js
    media
```

settings.py:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'emailcontactform',
    'corsheaders'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'acptconstruction')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'acptconstruction', 'build', 'static'),
]

if DEBUG: 
   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'backend','/static')
else:
   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') 

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 


CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://localhost:8000',
    'http://localhost:8080',
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`https://your_app.appspot.com/backend/static/js/2.738f0ca9.chunk.js` does not match any pattern in your `app.yaml`.  Either get rid of the `/backend/` part of the url, or add the handler to your `app.yaml`:

```
handlers:
- url: /static/css
  static_dir: static/css

- url: /backend/static/css
  static_dir: static/css

- url: /static/js
  static_dir: static/js

- url: /backend/static/js
  static_dir: static/js
```

And the mime_type error you saw was probably due to your tags in the template.html file.  The proper tags are:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

or:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

You don't want to put `text/html` in those tags.

Comment: Assuming this: 

```
runtime: python38

handlers:
- url: /backend/static/css/(.*)
  mime_type: text/css
 
- url: /backend/static/js/(.*)
  mime_type: text/javascript
```

Was your advice this still didn't resolve the error when I ran gcloud app deploy. Also, I didn't have text/html in those tags, I'm not sure why it interpretted it that way.

Comment: That wasn't supposed to be the entire handler.  You still have to tell it which directory to use.  See edit.

Comment: You're actually a superhero to me right now. Thank you so much that resolved the issue. There's a lingering problem, but I think i can see the path forward. I'm marking you as the answer, but I'm not sure I understand what happened here. Why do we have to call /static/css and /backend/static/css and does that just tell GAE where to get the css and js files? Why is this all needed if index.html tells it where to go?

Comment: Because the link that rendered in your html was `https://your_app.appspot.com/backend/static/js...`.  If you can make all the links render as `https://your_app.appspot.com/static/js...`, then you just need the one handler.  I'd bet that you used a relative path without a leading slash in a `/backend/...` page, so it was looking in `/backend/static/...`

Comment: Like `"static/js/main.js"` instead of `"/static/js/main.js"`